# android java Map merge with custom BiFunction

Tags: java, android, lambda, functional-interface

Using Java on Android, I want to merge an element into a Map with a custom remapping function.

```
Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();
// init map with some values here....  then
MyObject xMyObject = new MyObject(123); // init this instance of MyObject
map.merge("key", xMyObject, myRemappingFunction);
```

I understand Android Java does not have Java 8 support for lambda expressions. So I think I need to implement myRemappingFunction as a BiFunction, but I'm having trouble with understanding the BiFunction interface declaration to get anything to compile.

```
public static BiFunction<? super MyObject,? super MyObject,? extends MyObject> remappingfunction()
```

Any hints please?

Comment: A key fact that I didn't know, which contributed to my confusion prompting this question, is that the "<? super MyObject>" notation is called a "lower bound wildcard" for Java Generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `remappingFunction` is an implementation of `BiFunction<? super MyObject, ? super MyObject,? extends MyObject>` which is evaluated using the `apply` method that you need to define here.

Consider an example when you would merge the integer attribute `val` (by summing) of your `MyObject` if they are mapped to the same key, the implementation would look like :

```
map.merge("key", xMyObject, new BiFunction<MyObject, MyObject, MyObject>() {
    // this is the definition of what to do for two such values
    @Override
    public MyObject apply(MyObject myObject1, MyObject myObject2) {
        return new MyObject(myObject1.getVal() + myObject2.getVal());
    }
});
```

this could also be represented in *lambda* as :

```
map.merge("key", xMyObject, 
                (myObject1, myObject2) -> new MyObject(myObject1.getVal() + myObject2.getVal()));
```

Comment: Do note, for your case, since the type is always `MyObject` a specific implementation of `BinaryOperator<MyObject>` which extends `BiFunction` works as well.

Comment: Thanks! That gets to me a solution that compiles w/o error, and your first implementation answer is what I think I need to use, given the complex nature of my object merger. I'll approve as soon as I can verify my new code actually runs (shortly). Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Yay, I appear to have understood your answer enough to use it. I also see my confusion in my above comment about BinaryOperator<MyObject> being a specialization of BiFunction<MyObject,MyObject,MyObject>, I wouldn't have understood this document [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/function/BinaryOperator) without your concrete code example here. Using BinaryOperator<MyObject> appears to work just as well. They could have used that in the docs for Map.merge(). After all, could there be any other BiFunction<> where the 3 parameter types are not equal for use in Map.merge()?

Comment: @LarryTseng well the difference in the use of `BiFunction` there is that it allows you `? super V, ? super V, ? extends V` to get a return value of child type for input of parent types. While this won't have been possible using `BinaryOperator`, since that would have either been all `? super V` or `? extends V`.

Comment: Ah! I see now. Thanks!